# How to Pass Map in AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How to pass map object in AWS SQS queue?

I have a map object coming with some data and I wanted to pass the same map 
in AWS SQS queue in order to persist that. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to store the map so you can digest it from SQS later, as such I recommend you serialize it. You should serialize your data, as opposed to just sending the map into SQS and trying to parse it back into a map later, as it is much safer and likely easier.

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) and [MSGpack](http://msgpack.org/index.html) are popular for serialization and deserialization.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
some_map = {name: 'tom', age: 31}
serialized_map = make_into_json_function(some_map)
sqs.send_msg(queue, credentials, serialized_map)
```

To turn the JSON back into a map:

```
message = sqs.get_msg(some_msg_id)
new_map = make_json_into_map_function(message.text)
print new_map
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (and it is working 100%):

Tried to send map values as attributes in SQS : using setMessageAttributes, but since in SQS you can send max 10 attributes at a time thus it was not suiting my requirement (I was having more than 10 values in my map).

SQS provides an option to send message using messageBody as well so I converted my map into plain Json string and sending it to SQS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to serialize your map into a XML, JSON, or unformatted text.
When you receive messages, deserialize it to the map.
JSON can be a good choice, and you can use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to serialize/deserialize JSON.

Here are two [SQS limitations](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html#limits-messages) you should keep in mind:

1. Message content:

   > A message can include only XML, JSON, and unformatted text. The following Unicode characters are allowed: `#x9 | #xA | #xD | #x20 to #xD7FF | #xE000 to #xFFFD | #x10000 to #x10FFFF`
   >
   > Any characters not included in this list are rejected. For more information, see the W3C specification for characters.
2. Message size:

   > The minimum message size is 1 byte (1 character). The maximum is 262,144 bytes (256 KB).